# How to save selected for loop data in mysql database?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to spring boot and struck in a prob for some time now. In my thymeleaf page i have used a for loops and i need to save currently iterating item in the database.(ex:im using days of the week in a for loop and a user can select a subject for each item in my for loo, then 5 sql rows should be saved with day and subject) but currently it doesn't save the date and save 2 selected subjects in 1 sql row

Add time Table thymeleaf view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/timeTableMapping.css" th:href="@{/css/timeTableMapping.css}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Time Table</title>
</head>
<body>



</form>
<div class="container2">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/timeTableMapping/save}" th:object="${timeTableMapping}" method="post">
        <table border="0" cell[adding="10">
            <tr>
                <td><h1>Time Table:</h1></td>
                <td>
                    <select th:field="*{time_table_code}">
                        <option value="">Choose..</option>
                        <option th:each="timeTable: ${timeTables}" th:value="${timeTable.name}" th:text="${timeTable.name}"/>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table border="1" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
            </tr>
            <br>

            <th:block th:each="day : ${days}">
                <th th:value="${day.name}" th:text="${day.name}"></th>
            </th:block>


            </thead>
            <tbody>




                    <th:block th:each="day : ${days}">
                        <td>
                            <select th:field="*{subject_code}">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option th:each="subject: ${subjects}" th:value="${subject.subject_code}" th:text="${subject.name}"/>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </th:block>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>

                </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Time Table Mapping Controller

```
@Controller
public class TimeTableMappingController {
    @Autowired
    private  TimeTableMappingDAO timeTableMappingDAO;

    @Autowired
    private TimeTableDAO timeTableDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SubjectDAO subjectDAO;

    @Autowired
    private StudentGroupDAO studentGroupDAO;

    @Autowired
    private DayDAO dayDAO;



    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model){
        List<TimeTableMapping> timeTableMappingDetails= timeTableMappingDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("timeTableMappingDetails",timeTableMappingDetails);
        return "timeTableMapping";
    }



    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping/new")
    public String addTimeTableMapping(Model model){
        System.out.println("hey");
        System.out.println("hey");
        TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping =new TimeTableMapping();
        model.addAttribute("timeTableMapping",timeTableMapping);

        List<TimeTable> timeTableDetail = timeTableDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("timeTables", timeTableDetail);

        List<Subject> subjectDetail = subjectDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("subjects", subjectDetail);

        List<Day> dayDetails = dayDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("days",dayDetails);

        List<Time> timeDetails = timeDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("times",timeDetails);

        return "addTimeTableMapping";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/timeTableMapping/save",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTimeTable(@ModelAttribute("timeTableMapping") TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){

        timeTableMappingDAO.save(timeTableMapping);
        return  "redirect:/timeTableMapping";
    }

    /*
    @RequestMapping(value="/timeTableMapping/saveAll",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveAll(@ModelAttribute("timeTableMapping") TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){
        timeTableDAO.saveAll(timeTableMapping);
        return  "redirect:/timeTableMapping";
    }*/

    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView updateTimeTable(@PathVariable(name="id")Long id){
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView(("updateTimeTable"));

        TimeTable timeTable = timeTableDAO.findById(id);
        mav.addObject("timeTable",timeTable);

        List<Subject> subjectDetails = subjectDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("subjects", subjectDetails);

        List<StudentGroup> studentGroupDetails = studentGroupDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("studentGroups",studentGroupDetails);

        List<Day> dayDetails = dayDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("days",dayDetails);

        List<Time> timeDetails = timeDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("times",timeDetails);

        return  mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id){
        timeTableDAO.delete(id);
        return  "redirect:/timeTable";
    }
}
```

Add Time Table DAO

```
@Service
public class TimeTableMappingDAO {

    @Autowired
    TimeTableRepository timeTableRepository;

    @Autowired
    TimeTableMappingRepository timeTableMappingRepository;

    //to save a time table
    public TimeTableMapping save(TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){
        return timeTableMappingRepository.save(timeTableMapping);
    }

    //@Override
    public void saveAll(List<TimeTableMapping> timeTableMapping) {

        List<TimeTableMapping> timetable=new ArrayList<>();
        timeTableMappingRepository.saveAll(timetable).forEach(timeTableMapping::add);   // TimeTable repository
    }
/*
    public TimeTableMapping saveAll(TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){
        return timeTableMappingRepository.saveAll(timeTableMapping);
    }

*/
    //to search all 
    public List<TimeTableMapping> findAll(){
        return timeTableMappingRepository.findAll();
    }

    //get  by id
    public TimeTableMapping findById(Long id){
        return timeTableMappingRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }


    //delete 
    public void delete(Long id){
        timeTableMappingRepository.deleteById(id);
    }


}
```

Time Table Mapping Repository

```
  @Repository
public interface TimeTableMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<TimeTableMapping, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before auto wiring TimeTableMappingRepository in your DAO, you should add @Repository on interface TimeTableMappingRepository.

Just like this

@Repository
public interface TimeTableMappingRepository extends JpaRepository {}

By Adding @Repository on the interface, spring-data-jpa will create a proxy object of this interface on runtime and you will be able to autowired it.

Comment: thx for pointing out.I forgot to add it before.But still the error occurs

Comment: Why you do have added @Override on this method     public void saveAll(List<TimeTableMapping> timeTableMapping)

Comment: Please remove it as you don't have any parent class holding mentioned methods

Comment: hey i have removed it but using saveAll is not that much clear to me

Comment: Hi You have commented the original saveAll which is right and     public void saveAll(TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){
        return timeTableMappingRepository.saveAll(timeTableMapping);
    }

Comment: you mean the saveAll method i commented  public TimeTableMapping saveAll(TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){
        return timeTableMappingRepository.saveAll(timeTableMapping);
    }
is correct?

Comment: Do you want to save list in the database then you can use saveAll method which you commented for that you have to pass whole list to method                                      
public void saveAll(List<TimeTableMapping> timeTableMappingList) {
 repository.saveAll(timeTableMappingList);}

Comment: Commented method is also wrong. It should be    
    public void saveAll(List<TimeTableMapping> timeTableMapping){
         timeTableMappingRepository.saveAll(timeTableMapping);
    }

Comment: tried this but it still doesn't save day in the sql table

Comment: problem is in this method it doesn't pass day to the controller and i don't know how to do it.if you know a way please tell

Comment: Sorry late response, Actually in your thyme leaf  page for day , there is no input or select tag so that could be problematic while mapping form to object. You can see you subject code is using select tag but days not.

Comment: hey thx. But i'm not trying to use days in a dropdown that's why i didn't use a select tag. Is there any way to save the value of day ?

Comment: Then which day value you want pass then put into <input type="hidden" name="day" > so that spring model attribute could bind it.

Comment: now day is saved in the database but all the days and subjects are saved in the same sql row, even though i want to save each selected subject  in a different row.Asked the new prob in a different question. Can you check and answer for that please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248983/how-to-save-data-in-one-thymeleaf-page-in-multiple-sql-rows

Answer (score 0):

You are getting more than one data. So you should use `List<TimeTableMapping> timeTableMapping`

In your service Implementation, you can pass the list that you got adn save all

```
@Override
public void saveAll(List<TimeTableMapping> timeTableMapping) {

    List<TimeTableMapping> timetable=new ArrayList<>();
    repository.saveAll(timetable).forEach(timeTableMapping::add);   // TimeTable repository
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but when i use this in the service class it shows the error Error:(27, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: Sounds good, Since you are a beginner better you should know how  Repositories work in spring boot. I suggest you to get more knowledge in spring-boot and jpa repositories. https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-spring-data-jpa .Look on it, and find some more tutorials

Comment: thx a lot i will go through it.Btw can u suggest a way to solve this problem.And i have updated the question

Comment: i went through that article and it's really helpful and i read some articles about saveAll method in JPARepository and its still not clear to me.