# How to save data in one thymeleaf page in multiple sql rows

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

i'm new to spring-boot. In my thymeleaf page i have used a for loops to generate headers and have a dropdown under each of them.I need to save that header and selected dropdown item in one sql row.(ex:im using days of the week in a for loop as the header  and a user can select a subject under each header, and when a user select subjects and click submit button then 5 sql rows should be saved with day and subject) but currently it saves all the dates and subjects in 1 sql row [image]
[image]
[image]
addTimeTableMapping thymeleaf view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/timeTableMapping.css" th:href="@{/css/timeTableMapping.css}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Time Table</title>
</head>
<body>



</form>
<div class="container2">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/timeTableMapping/saveAll}" th:object="${timeTableMapping}" method="post">
        <table border="0" cell[adding="10">
            <tr>
                <td><h1>Time Table:</h1></td>
                <td>
                    <select th:field="*{time_table_code}">
                        <option value="">Choose..</option>
                        <option th:each="timeTable: ${timeTables}" th:value="${timeTable.name}" th:text="${timeTable.name}"/>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table border="1" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
            </tr>
            <br>

            <th:block th:each="day : ${days}">
                <th th:value="${day.name}" th:text="${day.name}"></th>
            </th:block>


            </thead>
            <tbody>




            <th:block th:each="day : ${days}">
                <td>
                    <select th:field="*{subject_code}">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option th:each="subject: ${subjects}" th:value="${subject.subject_code}" th:text="${subject.name}"/>
                        <td><input type="text"  th:value="${day.name}" name="day" style="display:none" /></td>

                    </select>
                </td>
            </th:block>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>

                </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

timeTable Mapping Controller

```
  @Controller
public class TimeTableMappingController {
    @Autowired
    private  TimeTableMappingDAO timeTableMappingDAO;

    @Autowired
    private TimeTableDAO timeTableDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SubjectDAO subjectDAO;

    @Autowired
    private StudentGroupDAO studentGroupDAO;

    @Autowired
    private DayDAO dayDAO;

    @Autowired
    private TimeDAO timeDAO;



    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model){
        List<TimeTableMapping> timeTableMappingDetails= timeTableMappingDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("timeTableMappingDetails",timeTableMappingDetails);
        return "timeTableMapping";
    }

    /*
    @RequestMapping ("/timeTableMapping/new")
    public String addTimeTableMapping(Model model) {
        TimeTableMappingDTO timeTablesForm = new TimeTableMappingDTO();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            timeTablesForm.addTimeTableMapping(new TimeTableMapping());
        }

        model.addAttribute("form", timeTablesForm);

        return "addTimeTableMapping";
    }
    */


    @RequestMapping(value="/timeTableMapping/saveAll",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTimeTable(@ModelAttribute("timeTableMapping") TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){

        String[] dayArray = timeTableMapping.getDay().split(",");
        String[] subArray = timeTableMapping.getSubject_code().split(",");


        List<TimeTableMapping> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < dayArray.length; i++) {
            TimeTableMapping tempTimeTable = new TimeTableMapping();
            tempTimeTable.setTime_table_code(timeTableMapping.getTime_table_code());
            System.out.println(timeTableMapping.getTime_table_code());
            tempTimeTable.setDay(dayArray[i]);
            System.out.println(dayArray[i]);
            tempTimeTable.setSubject_code(subArray[i]);
            System.out.println(subArray[i]);
            tempTimeTable.setStart(timeTableMapping.getStart());
            tempTimeTable.setEnd(timeTableMapping.getEnd());
            tempList.add(tempTimeTable);
        }
        timeTableMappingDAO.saveAll(tempList);
        return  "redirect:/timeTableMapping";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping/new")
    public String addTimeTableMapping(Model model){
        System.out.println("hey");
        System.out.println("hey");
        TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping =new TimeTableMapping();
        model.addAttribute("timeTableMapping",timeTableMapping);

        List<TimeTable> timeTableDetail = timeTableDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("timeTables", timeTableDetail);

        List<Subject> subjectDetail = subjectDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("subjects", subjectDetail);

        String[] days = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday"};

        List<Day> dayDetails = dayDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("days",dayDetails);

        List<Time> timeDetails = timeDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("times",timeDetails);

        return "addTimeTableMapping";
    }


/*

    @RequestMapping(value="/timeTableMapping/saveAll",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveAll(List<TimeTableMapping> timeTableMappingList) { timeTableMappingDAO.saveAll(timeTableMappingList);}

    @RequestMapping(value="/timeTableMapping/save",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTimeTable(@ModelAttribute("timeTableMapping") TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println(timeTableMapping.getId());
        System.out.println(timeTableMapping.getDay());
        System.out.println(timeTableMapping.getStart());
        System.out.println(timeTableMapping.getEnd());
        System.out.println(timeTableMapping.getSubject_code());
        System.out.println(timeTableMapping.getTime_table_code());
        timeTableMappingDAO.save(timeTableMapping);
        return  "redirect:/timeTableMapping/new";
    }
@RequestMapping(value="/timeTableMapping/saveAll",method= RequestMethod.POST) public String saveTimeTable(@ModelAttribute("timeTableMapping") TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){

String[] dayArray = timeTableMapping.getDay().split(",");
String[] subArray = timeTableMapping.getSubject_code().split(",");


List<TimeTableMapping> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < dayArray.length; i++) {
    TimeTableMapping tempTimeTable = new TimeTableMapping();
    tempTimeTable.setTime_table_code(timeTableMapping.getTime_table_code());
    tempTimeTable.setDay(dayArray[i]);
    tempTimeTable.setSubject_code(subArray[i]);
    tempTimeTable.setStart(timeTableMapping.getStart());
    tempTimeTable.setEnd(timeTableMapping.getEnd());
    tempList.add(tempTimeTable);
}
timeTableMappingDAO.saveAll(tempList);
    return  "redirect:/timeTableMapping";
}
    /*
    @RequestMapping(value="/timeTableMapping/saveAll",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveAll(@ModelAttribute("timeTableMapping") TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){
        timeTableDAO.saveAll(timeTableMapping);
        return  "redirect:/timeTableMapping";
    }*/

    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView updateTimeTable(@PathVariable(name="id")Long id){
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView(("updateTimeTable"));

        TimeTable timeTable = timeTableDAO.findById(id);
        mav.addObject("timeTable",timeTable);

        List<Subject> subjectDetails = subjectDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("subjects", subjectDetails);

        List<StudentGroup> studentGroupDetails = studentGroupDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("studentGroups",studentGroupDetails);

        List<Day> dayDetails = dayDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("days",dayDetails);

        List<Time> timeDetails = timeDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("times",timeDetails);

        return  mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id){
        timeTableDAO.delete(id);
        return  "redirect:/timeTable";
    }
}
```

timeTableMapping Repository

```
@Repository
public interface TimeTableMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<TimeTableMapping, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using form submission for saving complex data which is much complicated instead of that write java script and save your information in javascript object and send json string to controller for saving with list.

For now with your implementation simple hacky solution would be this.

1) saveTimeTable implementation with following

@RequestMapping(value="/timeTableMapping/saveAll",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTimeTable(@ModelAttribute("timeTableMapping") TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){

```
String[] dayArray = timeTableMapping.getDay().split(",");
String[] subArray = timeTableMapping.getSubject_code().split(",");  


List<TimeTableMapping> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < dayArray.length; i++) {
    TimeTableMapping tempTimeTable = new TimeTableMapping();
    tempTimeTable.setTime_table_code(timeTableMapping.getTime_table_code());        
    tempTimeTable.setDay(dayArray[i]);
    tempTimeTable.setSubject_code(subArray[i]);
    tempTimeTable.setStart(timeTableMapping.getStart());
    tempTimeTable.setEnd(timeTableMapping.getEnd());
    tempList.add(tempTimeTable);
}   
timeTableMappingDAO.saveAll(tempList);
    return  "redirect:/timeTableMapping";
}
```

Comment: Hey i  tried this.i think it worked upto some level but Still in the database it saves all the days and subjects in the same row.

Comment: hey, DB row structure updated and im not using any manual tableMapping class. Using auto mapping

Comment: Yes, you must have been creates a class of TimeTableMapping. But for now where is the problem with updated implementation.

Comment: You mean the DAO class i mentioned in the problem or a different one?

Comment: Thnak you this solved my problem. Needed a minor change. added this and it solved my problem String[] uniqueDay = Arrays.stream(dayArray).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);

Comment: Great, But remember this approach is error-prone so you should segregate your data at the client-side using javascript or more using more complex th tags with multiple forms.

Comment: thx will do it the next time i'm doing a similar project since i don't have much time to complete this.However it shows an error when i try to update timeTable. If you can plz help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58281672/error-trying-to-update-timetable-in-spring-boot?noredirect=1#comment102929058_58281672