# Error trying to update timeTable in spring boot

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i'm new to spring boot ad currently working on a timeTable generation support project.Add timeTable works properlyin my sysytem and now i want to update the TimeTable. However when i try to load the `upadteTimeTableView` it shows an error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/updateTimeTable.html]") Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "updateTimeTable" - line 18, col 46)
```

`updateTimeTable` Thymeleaf View

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/timeTableMapping.css" th:href="@{/css/timeTableMapping.css}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Update Time Table</title>
</head>
<body>



</form>
<div class="container2">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/timeTableMapping/saveAll}" th:object="${timeTableMapping}" method="post">
        <table border="0" cell[adding="10">
            <tr>
                <td><h1>Time Table:</h1></td>

                <td>
                    <select th:field="*{time_table_code}">
                        <option value="">Choose..</option>
                        <option th:each="timeTable: ${timeTables}" th:value="${timeTable.name}" th:text="${timeTable.name}"/>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table border="1" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <th></th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td >
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td>
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td >
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td>
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td >
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td>
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td >
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td>
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td >
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td>
            <td style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"></td>



            </thead>
            <tbody>

            <th:block th:each="time : ${times}">
                <tr>

                    <th th:text="${ time.start }+':00 - ' + ${ time.end }+':00'"></th>

                    <th:block th:each="day : ${days}">
                        <td>
                            <select th:field="*{subject_code}">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option th:each="subject: ${subjects}" th:value="${subject.subject_code}" th:text="${subject.name}"/>
                        <td><input type="text"  th:value="${day.name}" name="day" style="display:none;width:0px" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text"  th:value="${time.start}" name="start" style="display:none;width:0px" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text"  th:value="${time.end}" name="end" style="display:none;width:0px" /></td>


                        </select>
                        </td>
                    </th:block>

                </tr>


            </th:block>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`timeTableMapping` Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="timetablemappings")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class TimeTableMapping {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String day;
    private String start;
    private String end;
    private String subject_code;
    private String time_table_code;

    public TimeTableMapping () {
    }





    public TimeTableMapping(String day, String start, String end, String subject_code, String time_table_code) {
        this.day = day;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.subject_code = subject_code;
        this.time_table_code = time_table_code;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(String start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public String getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(String end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

    public String getSubject_code() {
        return subject_code;
    }

    public void setSubject_code(String subject_code) {
        this.subject_code = subject_code;
    }

    public String getTime_table_code() {
        return time_table_code;
    }

    public void setTime_table_code(String time_table_code) {
        this.time_table_code = time_table_code;
    }
}
```

`timeTableMapping` Controller

```
@Controller
public class TimeTableMappingController {
    @Autowired
    private  TimeTableMappingDAO timeTableMappingDAO;

    @Autowired
    private TimeTableDAO timeTableDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SubjectDAO subjectDAO;

    @Autowired
    private StudentGroupDAO studentGroupDAO;

    @Autowired
    private DayDAO dayDAO;

    @Autowired
    private TimeDAO timeDAO;



    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model){
        List<TimeTableMapping> timeTableMappingDetails= timeTableMappingDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("timeTableMappingDetails",timeTableMappingDetails);
        return "timeTableMapping";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/timeTableMapping/saveAll",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTimeTable(@ModelAttribute("timeTableMapping") TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){

        String[] dayArray = timeTableMapping.getDay().split(",");
        String[] subArray = timeTableMapping.getSubject_code().split(",");
         String[] startArray = timeTableMapping.getStart().split(",");
        String[] endArray = timeTableMapping.getEnd().split(",");

        String[] uniqueDay = Arrays.stream(dayArray).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
        String[] uniqueStart = Arrays.stream(startArray).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
        String[] uniqueEnd = Arrays.stream(endArray).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);


        List<TimeTableMapping> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<uniqueStart.length;j++) {

            for(int i = 0 ; i < uniqueDay.length; i++) {
                TimeTableMapping tempTimeTable = new TimeTableMapping();
                tempTimeTable.setStart(uniqueStart[j]);
                System.out.println(uniqueStart[j]);

                tempTimeTable.setEnd(uniqueEnd[j]);
                tempTimeTable.setTime_table_code(timeTableMapping.getTime_table_code());
                tempTimeTable.setDay(uniqueDay[i]);
                tempTimeTable.setSubject_code(subArray[count]);
                tempList.add(tempTimeTable);
                count++;

            }
        }

        timeTableMappingDAO.saveAll(tempList);
        return  "redirect:/timeTableMapping";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping/new")
    public String addTimeTableMapping(Model model){
        System.out.println("hey");
        System.out.println("hey");
        TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping =new TimeTableMapping();
        model.addAttribute("timeTableMapping",timeTableMapping);

        List<TimeTable> timeTableDetail = timeTableDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("timeTables", timeTableDetail);

        List<Subject> subjectDetail = subjectDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("subjects", subjectDetail);

        List<Day> dayDetails = dayDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("days",dayDetails);

        List<Time> timeDetails = timeDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("times",timeDetails);

        return "addTimeTableMapping";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView updateTimeTable(@PathVariable(name="id")Long id){
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView(("updateTimeTableMapping"));

        //mav.addObject("timeTableMapping", new TimeTableMapping());

        TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping = timeTableMappingDAO.findById(id);
        mav.addObject("timeTableMapping",timeTableMapping);

        List<TimeTable> timeTableDetails = timeTableDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("timeTables", timeTableDetails);

        List<Subject> subjectDetails = subjectDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("subjects", subjectDetails);

        List<StudentGroup> studentGroupDetails = studentGroupDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("studentGroups",studentGroupDetails);

        List<Day> dayDetails = dayDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("days",dayDetails);

        List<Time> timeDetails = timeDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("times",timeDetails);

        return  mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id){
        timeTableDAO.delete(id);
        return  "redirect:/timeTable";
    }
}
```

`timeTableMappingDAO`

```
@Service
public class TimeTableMappingDAO {

    @Autowired
    TimeTableRepository timeTableRepository;

    @Autowired
    TimeTableMappingRepository timeTableMappingRepository;


    //to save a time table
    public TimeTableMapping save(TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){
        return timeTableMappingRepository.save(timeTableMapping);
    }


    public void saveAll(List<TimeTableMapping> timeTableMapping){
        timeTableMappingRepository.saveAll(timeTableMapping);
    }

        //to search all 
    public List<TimeTableMapping> findAll(){
        return timeTableMappingRepository.findAll();
    }

    //get a machine by id
    public TimeTableMapping findById(Long id){
        return timeTableMappingRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }


    //delete
    public void delete(Long id){
        timeTableMappingRepository.deleteById(id);
    }


}
```

`timeTableMapping` Repository

```
@Repository
public interface TimeTableMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<TimeTableMapping, Long> {
}
```

[image: Databse]

This is the request 
http://localhost:8080/timeTable/edit/919

[image: Time Table View]

[image: Time Table View when select edit]
Update 1

Error was a syntax error and updated the files properly. Thx for everyone who tried to help

Comment: Please add the actual full stacktrace to the message and not a snippet. When doing so please wrap it in proper code tags.

Comment: thx a lot, but It's too long to include here however can see it https://github.com/Ayesh17/attendance/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your stack trace and found the line

89 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'timeTableMapping' available as request attribute at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]

The problem is here is that you binding an object to form which is **you are not passing through the controller or passing null object**. Maybe specified id is not available in the database, So from wherever you're calling this page to add an empty object there like following

1) If you are using ModelAndView class then just add an empty object in modelAndView
  modelAndView.addObject("timeTableMapping", new TimeTableMapping());

2) If you are using Model class then just add an empty object in model
   model.addAttribute("timeTableMapping", new TimeTableMapping());

Comment: hey thx, but specified id is in the database and even after i have added modelAndView.addObject("timeTableMapping", new TimeTableMapping()); it shows the same error

Comment: thx a lot but problem was a syntax error. However  when i try to load the `upadteTimeTableView` it shows the same subject in all the cells.(Since i have saved each subject in a unique row and when i select the id of that row it loads timeTable view with the same subject in all the cells.) Can you please tell me how to load the correct subject for each cell. time_table_code is same for all the rows

Comment: <select th:field="*{subject_code}">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option th:each="subject: ${subjects}" th:value="${subject.subject_code}" th:text="${subject.name}"/> Here you are loading every subject but not selecting anyone so by default first one will be shown there. You need to add thy tag and condition like this th:selected="${condition}"

Comment: Please refer this link for understanding https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-select-option

Comment: thing is when i select update it passes id of one row and it loads data of that row only. All the fields have a common column(time_table_code) and how can i load all the data with that common column  and pass it  to the update object?

Comment: could you update your generated webpage in question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58370109/update-timetable-in-spring-boot this is the actual problem i'm facing now. If u can please take a look